# Cardinality of set of finite subsets of $A$ equals cardinality of $A$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ be an infinite set and $\mathcal{F}(A)$ be the set of all finite subsets of $A$. Prove that $|A| = |\mathcal{F}(A)|$.

It is trivially true that $|A| \le |\mathcal{F}(A)|$. The idea, I think, is to find an injection from $\mathcal{F}(A)$ to $A$. To this end, let $f: A\to A$ be any function, then $f^{-1}(a) = F$, for $a\in A$, where $F$ is a fiber under $f^{-1}$. Let $(\mathcal{S}, f)$ be the collection of all fibers $F$ under all $f^{-1}$ on $A$ and denote $f(F_i)=a_i$ for all $i\in I$, then $f_i$ is an injection on a subset of $\mathcal{F}(A)$. Also, $\mathcal{F}(A)\subseteq (\mathcal{S},f)$. By the axiom of choice, there exists a choice function $j$ on $(\mathcal{S},f)$ such that $j[(\mathcal{F}(A),f)]\in (\mathcal{F}(A),f)$, for all $F\in \mathcal{F}(A)$. Let $f=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} f_i$ (defined as the intersection of the domains of all $f_i$), then $f:\mathcal{F}(A)\to A$ is injective. Hence, the conclusion holds.

I'm very new to the axiom of choice and this kind of the set theory, so would appreciate if you could point out any wrongdoings in my proof.

Comment: The collections of subsets of A with 0, 1, 2, 3, ... elements each has A many sets.  There are countabily many of them, so all together there are |N|.|A| = |A| many.

Comment: What if $A$ is uncountable? Then $\mathcal{F}(A)$ will contain all of the singletons $\{a\}$, for each $a\in A$. Then wouldn't it be true that $\mathcal{F}(A)$ is uncountable?

Comment: So what?  Both A and F(A) are uncountable.  You have a problem with that?

Comment: I'm confused. You said there are countably many subsets of $A$ (in your first comment above). But then you say there's no problem if $\mathcal{F}(A)$ is uncountable.

Comment: I said there are countably many collections of subsets of A.